# IMPORTDATA() on sheets not working for files in drive or google bucket

Tags: csv, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, google-bucket

I've been trying to use `=IMPORTDATA()` and it seems to only work in certain situations. Using the example URL in the `= IMPORTDATA("http://www.census.gov/2010census/csv/pop_change.csv")` I get no issue and it works as intended.

I have created a public bucket, with public files. When I use this: 
`=IMPORTDATA("https://storage.cloud.google.com/csvloadtest99/test1.txt")`

I get this output below, instead of my 10-row sample CSV file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta content="width=300  initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
      <meta name="google-site-verification" content="LrdTUW9psUAMbh4Ia074-BPEVmcpBxF6Gwf0MSgQXZs">
      <title>Sign in - Google Accounts</title>
      <style>   
         @font-face {   
         font-family: 'Open Sans';  
         font-style: normal;    
         font-weight: 300;  
         src: local('Open Sans Light')  local('OpenSans-Light')
         }  
         @font-face {   
         font-family: 'Open Sans';  
         font-style: normal;    
         font-weight: 400;  
         src: local('Open Sans')    local('OpenSans')
         }  
      </style>
      <style>
      h1    h2 {
      -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s; 
      -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;  
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; 
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;    
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0;

//    ...continues like this for hundreds of rows...
```

any ideas on how to resolve this? is this a setting issue on the bucket?

Comment: Use product tag Google-sheets first for your question to reach the right audience cc:@GBouffard

Comment: Your bucket doesn't seem to be public.